# what editor for Sharepoint 2010 aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, editor

I've tried several editors (Visuals Studio 2013, notepad++, sublime) but all of them show the code of the aspx pages a text. Non of them is doing any intending or syntax highlighting. 
All what I want is to open an aspx page via the explorer and edit it in a proper editor, can't be that complicated but I'm not going to make it.

Does anyone has an idea, what I should use. 
Do I need to activate some well hidden option, for proper intending?

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to find a very good text editor for aspx pages.

Personally I use brackets : http://brackets.io/

With Notepad++ your can choose the XML syntax highlighter. Before using brackets I was doing that.

There is a new text editor from Microsoft called 'Code':  https://code.visualstudio.com/

It looks not bad, maybe you could give it a try?

Comment: I tried both but both do not interpretate them correctly. IT just told me that those ASPX pages in the Intranet are not standard asp.net pages due to inherence from system layout but haven't got an acceptable suggestion how to deal with it.  
Any suggestion are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ASPX pages in the Intranet don't need to be necessarily  asp.net pages, as in my case, due to inherence from system layout.
So there are only two options either you use Share Point Designer what involves extra cost etc. or you design your text, web part or page in an standard brackets, visual studio. Afterwards you copy the entire code into that tiny window when you click 'show HTML source' when editing a page directly via the 'edit site' interface.